# identify the begin and end of PDF page in latex

Tags: pdf, page-numbering, rendering, page

Is it possible in Latex to identify where PDF pages begin and end?
E.g. PDF page X begins at line Y and ends at line Z in Latex.

Comment: Maybe this can be extracted from the synctex information?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. [What problem are you trying to solve?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/5763)